# Calling a path variable through GetObject()

Tags: vbscript

What I would like to do is that a variable created through `Set name = GetObject()` calls a variable which is a path created before, being `path = "Z:\vbscript\changeINVNR\batchInput.xlsx"`, and is directed to an Excel file.

My code, which doesn't work, is:

```
Set path = CreateObject("Z:\vbscript\changeINVNR\batchInput.xlsx")

Dim objExcel
Dim objSheet

Set objExcel = GetObject(path) 
Set objSheet = objExcel.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Which kind of object should be path in order to be called by `GetObject()` and how should it be created - as a string, object, others?

Comment: `Set path = CreateObject("...")` -> `path = "..."`

Comment: Hello Ansgar, I do not know what you mean but that structure produces a synthay error. Thanks

Comment: What structure? I told you replace one statement with another statement.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Sorry, I was taking the symbol "->" as an assignation. as the way I am very used in the R language!